# Handling Chinese characters with XML-RPC and MySQL

Tags: php, character-encoding, xml-rpc, cjk

I have an asynchronous web service in which users of a mobile app can post a comment on their phone, it uses JSON to upload the post to the API, and the server enters the post into the database, sending a confirmation back to the device. The server uses XML-RPC to pass messages around, but all communication with the device is done by JSON.

I am now trying to add support for Chinese characters. When I make a post from the device, this is how the JSON text looks when it is sent out:

```
Request object:

(
    {
        comment = "\U4e2d\U56fd";
        "post_id" = 119791544;
    }
)
```

That comment value represents the two Chinese characters 中国. When this is entered into the database it comes up as "??". Looking at the hex values this translates to 3F3F, so the database is definitely just storing question marks rather than having trouble displaying the characters. Also this means that the server understands that only two characters are coming through, so it recognises the character size of what's coming in. This is the function that is called when the server receives the data from the device:

```
function server_impl_post_comment($m)
{
    global $xmlrpcerruser;

    $auth = server_utils_authenticate_client();

    // return error if client is not authorised to use the api
    if (!$auth['result'])
    {
        return new xmlrpcresp(0, $xmlrpcerruser, $auth['reason']);
    }

    logger_api_log_method_call('ff.post_comment', $auth['user_id']);

    $args   = $m->getParam( 0 );

    $c['user_id'] = $auth['user_id'];
    $c['post_id'] = $args->structmem( "post_id" )->scalarval();
    $c['comment'] = $args->structmem( "comment" )->scalarval();

    // @todo: chinese characters come through as ? here

    // submit the comment
    $comment = post_comment($c);
    $post = post_get_post($c['post_id']);

    $result = server_utils_format_result_struct(TRUE, POST_COMMENT_TITLE, POST_COMMENT_MSG, POST_COMMENT_BUTTON, POST_COMMENT_SHOW, $c['post_id'], $comment);
    $result['post_info'] = server_utils_format_post_info($post);
    $result['post_up_votes'] = $post['post_vote_up_count'];
    $result['post_down_votes'] = $post['post_vote_down_count'];
    $result['post_comments'] = $post['post_comment_count'];

    return new xmlrpcresp(php_xmlrpc_encode($result));
}
```

At the @todo comment line I added a logging method, and $c['comment'] came through as "??" again. I tried logging the value of $m at the beginning but that didn't work for some reason. The XML-RPC library being used on the server is xmlrpc.inc v1.169 by Edd Dumbill and, as far as I know, this supports UTF-8. Any ideas as to where this is going wrong? I've been able to insert Chinese characters straight into the database with SQL so it must be something happening on the way in.

Answer (score 0):

Both your MySQL connection and the table-field collation must support Chinese characters. UTF unicode connections are a good bet.

For instance, make a call to `mysql_set_charset("utf8", $link)` to set the connection to UTF8 right after you call `mysql_connect();`

Comment: Thanks for the tip, although all of the MySQL stuff is in the post_comment function, and so wouldn't affect the value of $c['comment'] - therefore the error must be before that.

Comment: Oh, then is the character set for the POST communication for XML-RPC set correctly? If I'm right, the content being posted to the database are already garbled. You can log the content right where you've put your @todo to see if your content is correctly delivered to your script. If the content being logged is correct, then your database connection is at fault.

Comment: I've put a log function where the @todo is and it just logged the two question marks, so something must be happening before that. Could it be something to do with the encoding of the actual PHP file?

Comment: That could be the problem, yes, but after going over the phpxmlrpc documentation, it seems to me that the problem could be with the way the `scalarval` method handles strings in the `xmlrpcval` object. If the sent data is definitely correct, I'd suggest you go over the code for the library, or contact Edd Dumbill himself.